# Does Apache Phoenix Support PLSQL?

Tags: hadoop, plsql, hbase, hortonworks-sandbox

I want a procedural SQL mechanism in Phoenix. Is that possible? If not, what are my options? Some options I think are Spark and Pig integration with Phoenix.

Comment: Can you explain more, why you want to explore phoenix for PL/SQL. You can have UDF's with Spark SQL or Hive, but would depend on your use case.

Comment: http://www.hplsql.org/doc I doubt that works for Phoenix, though

Answer (score 0):

Since PL/SQL is a language for the Oracle database and Apache Phoenix is for Hadoop, I'd say no, it does not support PL/SQL.

Comment: I think the question is looking for HPL/SQL